# Why doesn't constructor call?

Tags: c++, constructor

I tried to examine behavior of the move constructor call:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(){ std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; };
    A(A&){ std::cout << "A(A&)" << std::endl; };
    A(A&&){ std::cout << "A(A&&)" << std::endl; };
};

A foo(){
    return A();
}

A t(A()); //produce no output, but because of A() is prvalue, I expected A(A&&) was produced
A d(foo()); //OK, produces A()\n A(A&&)\n A(A&&)

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/118c44a7f462c8e2)**

Could you explain that behavior?

Comment: `t` is not a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
A t(A());
```

is an abstract declaration of another function.

is a function declaration that has return type `A` and one parameter of type `A()` where `A()` in turn a function type-id.

Consider for example

```
#include <iostream>

int t( int() );
int t( int ( x ) ) { return x; }

int main() 
{
    std::cout << t( 10 ) << std::endl;
}
```

Here is `int()` is a type-id with an abstract declarator of a function. It is very

Consider another abstract declarator `char[10]`. There is also type-id with abstract declarator `[10]`. You could write for example

```
char ( ( [10] ) )
```

So this

```
void f( char ( ( [10] ) ) );
```

is a valid function declaration.

You may omit parameter identifiers if they are not used.

Comment: It's not obvous to me. Why is the declaration parsed so?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, Look up the most vexing parse. You can easily solve it by using `{}` instead of `()` to create the temporary (among other objects).

Comment: You said that it was a function. So why can't I call it? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28944e8abf7d599e .

Comment: Ah, because one declares a function takes one parameter of type _pointer to function, returning A_, not just A. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a4452ccd22940b4 . I've uderstood.

Comment: Shouldn't this say that `A t(A());` is a function declaration that takes one parameter, and that parameter is itself a *function* that takes no arguments and returns type `A`?

Comment: @jamesdlin I uodated my post.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have one more misunderstanding about what is the difference between _abstract-declarator_ and just _declarator_?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv In section 8.1 Type names of the C++ Standard there is written "1 To specify type conversions explicitly, and as an argument of sizeof, alignof, new, or typeid, the name of
a type shall be specified. This can be done with a type-id, which is syntactically a declaration for a variable
or function of that type that omits the name of the entity"